# Windows 7 how do I get rid of mobigenie malware

Tags: malware

How do I get rid of mobigenie it keeps changing my chrome search setting and attempting to install backup and driver software.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you meant mobogenie
The easiest way to do it is to install adware removal tools and scan your computer
A regular antivirus may not remove all components of this program

Here are some guides to uninstall it using antiadware softwares:
http://malwaretips.com/blogs/mobogenie-virus-removal/
http://www.securitystronghold.com/gates/remove-mobogenie.html

To remove it manually, first uninstall mobogenie from windows
This seems to be pretty straight forward
http://mobogenie.com/uninstall-guide.html
Then you will probably need to remove the browser extensions manually to get of the browser hijaking features
http://botcrawl.com/remove-mobogenie-virus/

It seems mobogenie gets installed while installing other freewqare programs. If that is how it entered your computer please carefully check all the dialog boxes that pop up during the program install to make sure that you do not install it again by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Malwarebytes is a great tool for removing misc malware but for last case scenarios, combofix always does the trick.